# Receiving data from Chamber through Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I am trying to establish a connection between my Client and an Espec Environmental Chamber.  When I send a command to the chamber, I receive no Data in return.  Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
import socket
from sys import argv, exit

ip = argv[1]
port = int(argv[2])
x = argv[3]


try:
    c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, e:
    print "Error creating socket:: %s" % e
    exit(1)
try:    
    c.connect((ip, port))
except socket.error, e:
    print "Connection error: %s" % e
    exit(1)
try:
    c.send(x)
except socket.error, e:
    print "Error sending data: %s" %e
    exit(1)

c.settimeout(10.0)

while True:
    try:
        buff = str(c.recv(4096))
    except socket.error, e:
        print "Error receiving data: %s" % e
        exit(1)
    if not len(buff):
        break
    print buff
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If so, can you post it?

Comment: There is no error message, hence why I set a timeout.